# Include custom fields in WordPress REST API search results

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

I am working on an application using the WP REST API to display data. I need to be able to search through data entered as a custom field. (I am using Advanced Custom Fields). I have expanded the REST API so that I can grab custom fields using the API. Now I need to include those fields within the searchable data for the post.

I want to search through an HTTP request:

```
http://example.com/wp-json/posts?type[]=post&filter[posts_per_page]=5&filter[s]=searchterm
```

In the above example, `searchterm` is the term that is being searched for. The above request works, but it will only search within title and content. So if `searchterm` is within either of those, then the search works but if `searchterm` is within a custom field then the search does not work.

Is there a way that I can expand the search function of the REST API so that I can search through custom fields?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Have you ever found a solution to this question?

Comment: @spik3s I was able to find a workaround for this that seems to have worked for V1 of the REST API. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this for the REST API V1 by using the Search Everything plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-everything/.